# Get rows with Group BY in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Let's assume I have the following table:

[image: example table]

I need the numbers from the column `'Shares'` ordered by `'Company'`.

So, Example:

> ABC, INC: 88624 + 5588 + 442214 + 11233
>
> DEF Corp.: 4556 + 444863 + 44601

Is there a way to do this using MySQL? Or maybe PHP?

Comment: group_concat perhaps?

Comment: `select company, sum(shares)
from your_table
group by company`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregate function is the best method:

```
SELECT SUM(shares), company
FROM table_name
GROUP BY company
```

The SUM() will do the necessary calculation of the same company name.
The GROUP BY will show them by company.

If you want specific companies not all (let's say 2 companies only):
You can add `WHERE Company = "ABC inc" OR "DEF Corp"`

Answer (score 2):

USE GROUP BY

```
SELECT COMPANY,SUM(SHARES) FROM <TABLE> group by COMPANY;
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
SELECT COMPANY,SUM(SHARES) FROM <TABLE> group by COMPANY;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to list all the SHARES, you can use group_concat and group by:

```
 select company, group_concat(SHARES) 
 from my_table 
 group by company
```

If you want the sum of share, use:

```
 select company, sum(SHARES) 
 from my_table 
 group by company
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below mentioned query

```
select COMPANY, sum(shares) from table_name group by COMPANY ;
```

And if you don't want the sum and only need it for display, use:

```
select COMPANY, GROUP_CONCAT( shares SEPARATOR '+' )from     
table_name group by COMPANY
```

Answer (score 1):

u can use aggregation function **SUM()** in the sql

```
select COMPANY,SUM(SHARES)
from ur_table
group by COMPANY
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the sum, use `sum()`.  If you want a list, then use `group_concat()`:

```
select company,
       sum(shares) as sum_shares,
       group_concat(shares separator '+') as list_shares
from t
group by company;
```

The `separator` keyword allows you to put in a `+`.

Answer (score 1):

use this `query`

select COMPANY,SUM(SHARES)
from table_name
group by COMPANY